# Detect Objective C event from PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I want notification in phonegap  when any event/method get call in Objective C code?

Thanx in advance

Comment: @Joe: but its mandatory 4 me...

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke your Javascript logic from Objective C by calling "stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString" on the WebView object:

```
NSString* jsCallback = @"alert(\"Alert from Objective C!\");";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallback ];
```